# Estimated tax payments in VA

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, state-income-tax, virginia

I lived in the US in 2014, and I got a salary from a company located in Virginia (VA) in 2014 and 2015. I didn't file the VA tax return back then and I want to sort it out now. I did file the federal tax return on time.

I'm not from the US and the tax system puzzles me sometimes. I've found the "estimated tax payments" concept for the first time in the VA form 760. If I got it correctly, they are payments that taxpayers must make in advance when the taxes withheld from the salary are lower than the taxes we have to pay.

I did not make any estimated tax payment in 2014 or 2015. How should I deal with them now?

Since I'm late on filing in the state return for 2014 and 2015, may I just type "0" in the "estimated tax payment" entry and complete the forms normally?

If 2014 return results in me having to pay additional state taxes, does it affect the estimated tax payments?

Do I have to fill in the 2014 and 2015 forms that calculate the "estimated tax payment" for the following year (form 760ES for VA)?

As an aside, do federal taxes affect the amount of state taxes that I have to pay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To complete your back taxes for the state of Virginia you will need your federal tax forms for those years, because many items on the Federal form end up on the state form. That is the big impact that the federal tax process has your your state taxes.

Assuming that your employer withheld state taxes and gave you a W-2 for those years, there is no need to worry about the VA 760ES form. That form is for the situation where the you know that you will owe a lot of money to the state next year, and your withholding will not cover it.

In your situation if you owe money for those late tax forms you will have to pay them when you file. In cases where taxpayers itemize, the amount they pay when  they file or the amount refunded when they file can play a role in their taxes the following year. In your case that won't be true. The amount you owe or receive this spring for all your tax forms be reflected in the numbers you file next year.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Two questions: in the second paragraph, you actually mean VA 760ES form (Estimated Income Tax Payment) instead of VA 760 (Resident Individual Income Tax Return), don't you? I mean, I do have to file VA 760.
Then, I can set the "estimated tax payments" to 0 en the forms that I'm going to file, and attach a payment with them I owe money. Is this correct?